# Should i stop native apache and mysql when running docker?

Tags: docker

I have installed MySQL and apache using brew on my local machine and have been using them for several php project environments. Now i want to start learning docker to containerize a new Laravel environment ([example](https://laradock.io)) . Before i start using docker on my local machine, should i stop the httpd and mysql service ? will the 'php' and 'mysql' command have a conflict ?

Answer (score 1):

The only issue you might have running the same services in containers as locally on your machine is a port conflict. Let's take httpd as an example:

- You try and start the container and you get `listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use`. This is because a HTTP server is already running on your machine.
- Tell docker to bring the container up using a different local port: `docker run -p 80:8080 <your container, commands etc>`. This will tell Docker to bind port `80` in the container to port `8080` on your machine.
- You can now access both `http://localhost:80` (your machine) and `http://localhost:8080` (the container).

Comment: will there be a conflct with mysql and php command in terminal ?